# Overlapping cells in table like pages in a book

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a series of forms that the user can fill out and add as many forms as one would like. These forms will vary in height (Important later) and can be minimized. Right now I have them in a table surrounded by a fixed position div with overflow auto. The reason they are in a table is so I can have them glued to the bottom of the page no matter the height. What I want is for the table cells to act kind of like pages in a book, I want every new form created to sit next to the previous one until there is no more space. When the width of the page has been filled I want them to start overlapping as much as needed to evenly space them. Also when a form is clicked It would be brought to the front. Below is a crude drawing and an example of what I have so far.

This is Gibberish in my head so if you find any of it confusing please ask.

Question: What I want is for the table cells to act kind of like pages in a book, I want every new form created to sit next to the previous one until there is no more space. When the width of the page has been filled I want them to start overlapping as much as needed to evenly space them. Also when a form is clicked It would be brought to the front. Below is a crude drawing and an example of what I have so far. How do I do this?

[Pages in a book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9sbQ.png)

```js
$('#AddForm').click(function (){
  var Target = $('#Fixed').find('tr');
  var height = Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50;
  var HEX = '3456789ABCD';
  var Color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
      Color += HEX[Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)];
  }
  var Form = $("<div>Form</div>").css("background", Color).css('height', height+"px");
  var Cell = $("<td class='Form' valign='bottom'></td>")
  Cell.append(Form)
  Target.append(Cell)
});
```

```css
#Fixed{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.FullWidth{
  width: 100%
}
.Form div{
  width: 200px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
#AddForm{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='AddForm'>Add Form</button>
<div id='Fixed'>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class='FullWidth'></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JohnH Updated with separate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this work with flexbox. Here's the css, the rest is in the fiddle:

```
#fixed{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.form{
  width: 200px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.form + .form{margin: 0 0 0 -20px;}

#addForm{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7np8pm53/1/